# How to exclude the input of special characters in Batch using findstr?

Tags: batch-file, special-characters, findstr, errorlevel

I'm writing a Batch game and am having some difficulty. I'm making a character creation, and the player can input a name of their choice. I'm trying to detect if they type in special characters by using the `findstr` command. I've been looking around, but all the other fixes on this website haven't been working for me. I'm not very advanced in Batch, so a simple answer would be preferred, otherwise a detailed explanation would be much appreciated. Delayed expansion is enabled.
Here is the code I have.

```
:charactername
cls
echo We know your Username is !username!, but what will your character's name be?
echo.
set /p character="Type a character name.> "
if "!character!"=="" (
    echo Please type a valid name.
    timeout 3 /nobreak > nul
    goto charactername
)
echo !character! | findstr /R " ^^! @ # $ %% ^ && * ) ( _ = + \] \[ } { \ | ; : "" < > ^, \. / ? ^` ~ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0" 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    cls
    echo Please do not use any special characters or numbers for your character's name.
    echo Only - and ' are accepted.
    timeout 5 /nobreak > nul
    goto charactername
) else (
    goto nameconfirm
)
```

This is what I want each section to do.

`if "!character!"==""` detects if the player enters nothing. This is working fine.

`` echo !character! | findstr /R " ^^! @ # $ %% ^ && * ) ( _ = + \] \[ } { \ | ; : "" < > ^, \. / ? ^` ~ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0" 2>nul `` : I want this section to detect if the player entered any of these characters. I'm not sure if this command is formatted correctly; please advise.

`if %errorlevel%==0` : Based on my other research on StackOverflow, apparently I can use this to detect if the `findstr` command found any of the special characters. I have also tried using `if %errorlevel%==1`. The problem here is that if I use the first option, it skips to the `else` section regardless of special characters. If I detect if the errorlevel is at 1, it doesn't allow anything through, displaying the error message I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use a `FOR /F` command and use all the characters of the alphabet as delimiters. If the `FOR` command outputs any data then you know they didn't use only alpha characters.

```
for /F "delims=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" %%G IN ("%character%") Do IF NOT "%%~G"=="" @ECHO Bad Character Name
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I just replaced the `echo` at the end with a `goto badname`.